# android : Layout size changes on Orientation

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, screen-rotation

I am facing a problem with me Layout. I am trying to build one xml file that operates both on landscape and portrait. On one specific Layout, on rotation (from portrait to landscpe) the Layout seems to expand itself. Although, every single object is there, I get a big gap.

This is how it is on Portrait.

[image]

These depict how it is after rotation (Landscape).

[image]

My xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>



<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        android:id="@+id/coordintorLayout">



        <com.andremion.floatingnavigationview.FloatingNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/floating_navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
            app:drawMenuBelowFab="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_view_header"
            app:menu="@menu/menu" />

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                layout="@layout/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/footer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="bottom|center">

                    <!--
                    <include
                        layout="@layout/single_item_customize"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                    -->
                    <ViewStub
                        android:id="@+id/layout_stub1"
                        android:inflatedId="@+id/inflated_layout_stub1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.75" />

                    <ViewStub
                        android:id="@+id/layout_stub2"
                        android:inflatedId="@+id/inflated_layout_stub2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.75" />
                    <ViewStub
                        android:id="@+id/layout_stub3"
                        android:inflatedId="@+id/inflated_layout_stub3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.25" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0px"
                        android:layout_weight="0.25"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:id="@+id/editText"
                        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:editable="false"
                        android:enabled="false"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                        android:freezesText="false"
                        android:linksClickable="false"
                        android:longClickable="false"
                        android:text="@string/default_message" />
                </LinearLayout >
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I am pretty sure that something is wrong with my xml, but I cannot figure it out.

Thanks in Advance.

PS: I have already the

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
```

inside my manifest.

Comment: Hi. Please don't edit your solution into the text of the question. On Stack Overflow, a question is considered solved when it has an accepted answer. Please post the solution you edited in as an answer instead and mark it as accepted (there might be a 24-hour limit preventing you from accepting your own answer, so you'll have to wait about 10 more hours).

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. Changed it.

Answer (score 1):

You should re implement the layout with the same name under layout-land
so your file structure should be as follow :

```
MyProject/
    res/
        layout/              # default (portrait)
            main.xml
        layout-land/         # landscape
            main.xml
```

i hope this will help you :)

Comment: Thanks. I bet this is one of the "good practices" - (newbie here). I am trying to implement this, by using one xml per intent (if it can be done).

Answer (score 1):

found the solution.

Changed the:

`android:layout_gravity="center"` inside the second LinearLayout, with 
`android:layout_gravity="top|center"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `android:fillViewport="true"` and change your `layout_height` attribute to `match_parent` in your `ScrollView`.

Comment: Thanks. It didn't work. I keep getting the same output.